# calling a method from tkinter class

Tags: python, class, tkinter, methods

I'm very new on Python and trying to develop a fake data generator software for data scientists to be able to learn faster.
My question is about how we can call a method from a sub method between tkinter object classes. I have root class which creates root window and toplevel class which creates toplevel (sub-window). 
My sub-window class needs to update a widget in root window and I couldn't have done it.

`enter code here`

```
class Menu():
    def __init__(self,master):
    ....
    def openwindow(self):
        secondwindow = my_sub_window(root)
    def dosomething(self):
        ....

class my_sub_window():
    def __init__(self, master):
        update_root()
    def update_root(self):
        dosomething()  # How can I call dosomething method in Menu() class?

root = Tk()
myApp = Menu(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What if you had two Menus? how would the `my_sub_window` class know which one should handle `dosomething`? If you're thinking "that will never happen. I'm certain I will only ever have one Menu", then you should consider whether Menu needs to be a class in the first place. (I'm not saying that it definitely shouldn't be a class; just something to think about)

Comment: You call class methods with the following syntax `Class.Method()`. Your example would be `Menu.dosomething(self)`

Comment: @gbeaven: that may not work like you expect, if `self` in the caller isn't an instance of `Menu`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, you would call the function based off of the global `myApp` class:

```
class my_sub_window():
    def update_root(self):
       myApp.dosomething()
```

Though, it's generally not a good idea to rely on global variables like this. The most common solution is to pass the instance of `Menu` to the `my_sub_window` class.

Example:

```
class Menu():
    def openwindow(self):
        secondwindow = my_sub_window(root)
        ...

class my_sub_window():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
    def update_root(self):
        self.root.dosomething()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. "myApp.dosomething()"